# I faced some implicit wait issues using python code in app automation on BrowserSatcks cloud platform

Tags: python, appium

How to solve this issue, I have used some cloud-based real device platforms on those I used the same code for the automation but in this platform, the code is not working the major issue it is showing is as I mentioned.

error : selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Parameters were incorrect. We wanted "MJSONWP protocol requires type and ms" and you sent {"implicit":10000}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/accca.png)

Comment: please provide your code in proper format